# passiv RFID or NFC tag with high range

Tags: rfid, nfc

I am searching the internet for quiete a while now to find out which **passiv** RFID Tags and which **passiv** NFC Tags have have the highest read/write distance. I am aksing here because the most information I found is pretty old (like from 2009) and I can´t believe that there are no better system till today.

I saw tutorials: for example which show how to boost your readers antena to get a read/write distance for NFC tags of about 1 metre. But is this allready the maximum ?

I would be really happy if someone who is experienced in this field can point me to sources for state of the art systems of this field with the highest possible read/write distance for both RFID and NFC tags.

Comment: It´s ok for me if you downvote, but it would help me for the future if you tell me why

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you were either too lazy to read the rules or too arrogant to care.

Comment: Downvotes might be because NFC and high range are a mutual contradiction, unless you are make planetary size tags.

Answer (score 2):

*I can´t believe that there are no better system till today.*

Please define "better".

What you think is "better" does not mean everyone agrees.

NFC is supposed to be secure, **increasing** the possible reading distance makes it **less secure**.  RFID is similar in that it is also supposed to work only for small range. 1 meter sounds reasonable to me for RFID applications (holding a badge near a reader to get access). If you need a larger reading distance, then I think RFID and NFC are not what you need.

Also note that passive tags can be passive because they draw their energy from the reader. You would need gigantic antenna coils on both the tag and the receiver to be able increase the reading distance and still have enough power in the tag for it to operate. Although the tags are called "passive" there is a chip in there which is active when it is communicating with the reader.

Comment: +1. It's questions like this that made me send my contactless card back to the bank for a good old Chip&Pin one.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I **love** contactless :-) In my country I can use it since few months and I think it's great. And it only works if I hold my card **very** close to the reader (I'm talking a few centimeters) so I'm not concerned regarding it's security. I'm surprised though that you'd need a new card for the traditional PIN/Chip as my card can do all of that as well :-)

Comment: Contactless had chip&pin too, I just complained because I didn't feel like cutting or drilling to remove the antenna! Then after being told it was impossible, (and cutting out the ant) the contact-only card arrived out of the blue months later. So either I wasn't the only one who complained, or Clydesdale Bank deserves kudos for exceptional service!

Comment: Aha I see ! I now wonder if it would be possible to zap the NFC chip using a ridicolous alternating magnetic field. I mean, if you induce enough magnetic flux, resulting in too much voltage at the antenna input, it should break at some point. I know the chips have overvoltage protection but those also have their limits. I have some old NFC tags I might try to zap one day :-)

Comment: The trick is not to destroy the Chip&Pin at the same time, hence mechanical methods. Or Faraday cage wallets, or avoiding crowded tube trains... But it's nice if the banks have decided to allow opt outs instead.